# How to address explicit widget id warning for a shiny app using metricsgraphics?

Tags: r, shiny, metricsgraphicsjs

I've built a shiny application that uses metricsgraphics to create histogram. When running the application I get the following error message:

Warning in `output$histPlot`(...) :
  Ignoring explicitly provided widget ID "mjs-acd1c2bc860bf1a81780a7603d6f7b"; Shiny doesn't use them

[The only place I've seen this warning discussed is on the issues page for metricsgraphics](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/metricsgraphics/issues/30) but no solution is provided. My app can be run with the following command:

shiny::runGitHub(repo = 'mihiriyer/mental')

My code is located here: https://github.com/mihiriyer/mental/blob/master/app.R

The app seems to work fine and so should even be worried since it is just a warning? Should I just suppress the message and move on?

Answer (score 6):

Apparently not much can be done other than suppressing the warning message. Posted my question on Github, the response I got is here:
https://github.com/hrbrmstr/metricsgraphics/issues/49

Basically, one can add the following line to the server function section and the warnings will be suppressed:

`options(warn = -1)`