# How to handle the Warning "Ignoring explicitly provided widget ID ; Shiny doesn't use them"?

Tags: plotly, r-plotly

I have already gone through similar questions previously posted here on StackOverflow such as 
[How to address explicit widget id warning for a shiny app using metricsgraphics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39452813/how-to-address-explicit-widget-id-warning-for-a-shiny-app-using-metricsgraphics), but the fixes proposed are not showing any results for me. On the dashboard, only a blank plot shows up, that is only with the plot background with layout etc. I have checked the scales and layout rules twice and the plots work fine. I am very much new to shiny. 
Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the elementId to NULL should do the trick:

**`p$elementId <- NULL`**

Full example:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("p")
)

server <- function(input, output, ...) {

  output$p <- renderPlotly({
    p <- plotly_build(qplot(1:10))
    p$elementId <- NULL
    p
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Look also at that [github-issue](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/985).